# How to make Nextjs show typescript type errors on save

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I'm working with a Nextjs Typescript project and get that the type errors don't stop the app execution as another kind of error, that's a problem to me, but is a bigger problem since the `TypeError` occurs at the build time, discovering that has type errors mostly when need to make a deploy.

Is there a way to make `typescript errors` block the app execution while developing? What config should I use to reach this?

That is my `tsconfig.json`

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2020",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "paths": {
      "~components/*":["src/components/*"],
      "~styles/*":["src/styles/*"],
      "~store/*":["src/store/*"],
      "~snippets/*":["src/snippets/*"],
      "~utils/*":["src/utils/*"],
      "~interfaces/*":["src/interfaces/*"],
      "~services/*":["src/services/*"],
      "~transformer/*":["src/transformer/*"],
    }
  },
  "include": [
    "next-env.d.ts",
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.tsx"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```